# How to remove version and thank you message from the admin footer

Tags: footer

I've used following codes and no luck

**1**

```
//Hide admin footer from admin
function change_footer_admin () {
    return ' ';
}
add_filter('admin_footer_text', 'change_footer_admin', 9999);

function change_footer_version() {
    return ' ';
}
add_filter( 'update_footer', 'change_footer_version', 9999);
```

**2**

```
function wpbeginner_remove_version() {
return '';
}
add_filter('the_generator', 'wpbeginner_remove_version');
```

**3**

```
function my_footer_shh() {
    remove_filter( 'update_footer', 'core_update_footer' ); 
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_footer_shh' );
```

Still I see those texts and version on my footer.
[image: have a look at the screen shot]

So what is the accurate way to remove these?
I've added these code snippets into my **child theme function.php**

Comment: Where did you try these code snippets?

Comment: into my functions.php

Comment: and I am using a child theme.

Comment: it's working. My file name was **function.php** Now I renamed it as **functions.php** and now its working. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: Admin Footer Text Remover **/

add_filter( 'admin_footer_text', '__return_empty_string', 11 );
add_filter( 'update_footer',     '__return_empty_string', 11 );
```

where I use the [`__return_empty_string`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_empty_string) function as a callback.

Comment: thanks for that. But still same. Is any possible it's because of Wordpres version? I am using 3.9.2

Comment: and I am using a child theme.

Comment: it's working. My file name was **function.php** Now I renamed it as **functions.php** and now its working. Thanks for your time.